# Linq Join: Join using a mapping table and associate objects

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to write a linq query to make a very basic join. I have two arrays

```
Park[] parks = new Park[]{
                new Park() {ID = 1, Name = "Free Park"},
                new Park() {ID = 2, Name = "Cost Park"},
                new Park() {ID = 3, Name="Sneak in Park"}
};
```

and

```
Facility[] facilities = new Facility[] {
                new Facility() { ID = 1, Name = "Swing", MinimumAge = 1, MaximumAge = 120},
                new Facility() { ID = 2, Name = "Slide", MinimumAge = 1, MaximumAge = 200},
                new Facility() { ID = 3, Name = "See-Saw", MinimumAge = 1, MaximumAge = 300}
};
```

Each park can have `0...n` facilities, hence we have a set of mapping objects

```
ParkFacility[] associations = new ParkFacility[] {
                new ParkFacility() {ParkID = 1, FacilityID = 1},
                new ParkFacility() {ParkID = 1, FacilityID = 2},
                new ParkFacility() {ParkID = 1, FacilityID = 3},
                new ParkFacility() {ParkID = 2, FacilityID = 1},
                new ParkFacility() {ParkID = 3, FacilityID = 2}
};
```

This is the definition of the class `Park`

```
class Park
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Facility[] Facilities { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to use only joins and associate the appropriate facilities to the parks? i.e. set the `Facilities` array in Park to be those appropriately mapped using the `associations`?

### Edit: My research thus far..

```
var x_temp = from g in parks
             join j in associations on g.ID equals j.ParkID into h
             select new Park()
             {
                Name = g.Name,
                ID = g.ID,
                Facilities = (from u in h join m in facilities on u.FacilityID equals m.ID select m).ToArray()
             };
```

I tried using a sub-linq query and it works, but I am looking for a solution with **only** joins

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems have you had with your current attempts to use `Join`?  What research have you done on how to use the `Join` operation, and how, specifically, has it failed to help you solve your problem.

Comment: added it in, I will keep you posted on more I work on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup from park id to facilities, and use this to populate the `Facilities` property on each of your `Park` objects. Note that the best place to do this is in the constructor of `Park`, but in keeping with your existing code this snippet will do it in the object initializer:

```
var lookup = associations.ToLookup(pf => pf.ParkID, pf => facilities.Single(f => f.ID == pf.FacilityID));
Park[] parks = new Park[]{
    new Park() {ID = 1, Name = "Free Park", Facilities = lookup[1].ToArray()},
    new Park() {ID = 2, Name = "Cost Park", Facilities = lookup[2].ToArray()},
    new Park() {ID = 3, Name="Sneak in Park", Facilities = lookup[3].ToArray()}
};
```

Additionally, it would be helpful to store all your `Facility` and `Park` instances in a `Dictionary` mapping the ID to the instance. In that case your lookup wouldn't need to do a linear scan through the all the facilities for each association.

Comment: I think your solution is sleek! :D, I have a question though, what would happen if I use it on 3 SQL tables (with ADO. NET) with the same concept? would it be efficient?

Comment: @Lordbalmon I don't know, you'd have to measure to see if it is good enough for your use case. Like I've mentioned in the answer, using a data structure that is indexed by the ID of the entity is going to improve this code significantly. If you used `Dictionary<int, Facility>` to store the facilities, you could replace `facilities.Single(f => f.ID == pf.FacilityID)` with `facilities[pf.ID]`, which is a difference of `O(n)` vs `O(1)`.